# How to pass a string value to a Sentiment Analysis RNN Sequential Model and get back a prediction

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, recurrent-neural-network, sentiment-analysis

I recreated a sentiment analysis machine learning project using my own data set along with some minor modifications to improve its completion time, I can create good model, compile it, fit it and test it without issues, the problem comes however on how to pass the model a new string/ article and it in return pass a prediction on whether the string comments are positive or negative and was hoping someone could help me.

I posted my code below for your review.

```
class tensor_rnn():
def __init__(self, corp_paths, hidden_layers=3, loadfile=True):
    self.h_layers = hidden_layers
    self.num_words = []
    if loadfile == False:
        data_set = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Article', 'Polarity'])
        craptopass = []
        for files in os.listdir(corp_paths[0]):
            with open(corp_paths[0] + '\\' + files, 'r', errors='replace') as text_file:
                line = text_file.readline().replace('|', '')
                text_file.close()
            if len(line.split(' ')) > 3:
                line = ''.join([i if ord(i) < 128 else ' ' for i in line])
                craptopass.append([line, 1])
        good = data_set.append(pd.DataFrame(craptopass, columns=['Article', 'Polarity']), ignore_index=True)
        data_set = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Article', 'Polarity'])
        craptopass = []
        for files in os.listdir(corp_paths[1]):
            with open(corp_paths[1] + '\\' + files, 'r', errors='replace') as text_file:
                line = text_file.readline().replace('|', '')
                text_file.close()
            if len(line.split(' ')) > 3:
                line = ''.join([i if ord(i) < 128 else ' ' for i in line])
                craptopass.append([line, -1])
        bad = data_set .append(pd.DataFrame(craptopass, columns=['Article', 'Polarity']), ignore_index=True)
        for line in good['Article'].tolist():
            counter = len(line.split())
            self.num_words.append(counter)

        for line in bad['Article'].tolist():
            counter = len(line.split())
            self.num_words.append(counter)
        self.features = pd.concat([good, bad]).reset_index(drop=True)
        # self.features = self.features.str.replace(',', '')
        self.features.to_csv('Headlines.csv', sep='|')
    else:
        self.features = pd.read_csv('Headlines.csv', sep='|')
        self.features['totalwords'] = self.features['Article'].str.count(' ') + 1
        self.num_words.extend(self.features['totalwords'].tolist())

    self.features = shuffle(self.features)
    self.max_len = len(max(self.features['Article'].tolist()))
    tokenizer = self.tok = preprocessing.text.Tokenizer(num_words=len(self.num_words), split=' ')
    self.tok.fit_on_texts(self.features['Article'].values)
    X = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(self.features['Article'].values)
    self.X = preprocessing.sequence.pad_sequences(X)
    self.Y = pd.get_dummies(self.features['Polarity']).values
    self.X_train, self.X_test, self.Y_train, self.Y_test = train_test_split(self.X, self.Y,
                                                                            test_size=0.20, random_state=36)

def RNN(self):
    embed_dim = 128
    lstm_out = 128
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Embedding(len(self.num_words), embed_dim, input_length=self.X.shape[1]))
    model.add(Bidirectional(CuDNNLSTM(lstm_out)))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))
    model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))
    opt = Adam(lr=0.0001, decay=1e-4)   #1e-3
    model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=opt, metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model

def model_train(self):
    self.model = self.RNN()

def model_test(self):
    batch_size = 128
    self.model.fit(self.X_train, self.Y_train, epochs=4, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=2,
                                callbacks=[EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', min_delta=0.0001,
                                                         patience=5, verbose=2, mode='auto')], validation_split=0.2)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    paths = 'PATHS TO ARTICLES'
    a = tensor_rnn([paths + '\\pos', paths + '\\neg'])
    a.model_train()
    a.model_test()
    a.model.save('RNNModelArticles.h5', include_optimizer=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is preprocess the new text that you want to feed to the model the same way you preprocessed text for the training. After that, you should have a predict method that will output it's prediction in the same way the model outputs prediction in the training. So, in the predict method you should write something like:

```
def predict(self, sequence):
  presprocessed = preprocess(sequence)
  prediction = self.model.predict(preprocessed, batch_size=None, verbose=0, steps=None)
```

Does this clarify things for you?

Comment: Hi Novak, I think we are getting close, preprocessing the string input does make sense, the problem now however is that the expected dimensions and the dimensions of the string input do not mach (please see below).
Error when checking input: expected embedding_input to have shape (119,) but got array with shape (4,)

Comment: So your problem is that the sentences (or just input) are not of the same length? If that is a problem, just pad everything you put into model to a specified length, in this case 119. For padding you can use some neutral word or something like that (for example `a` as an adjective is neutral and therefore will not affect the outcome of the sentiment analysis)

Comment: Hi Novak, sorry for the late update, I followed your advice I am finally able to make predictions with my model. Thank you for your help.